# Excel VBA AutoFilter issue (field value)

Tags: vba, excel, filter, field

I can't find a solution to my code problem.

Let's say I have this recordset

```
AR1         AR2                 AR7     AR8 AR9
2015-02-28  Residential Pool    ND,5    BDM IT0538700021972
2015-02-28  Residential Pool    ND,5    BDM IT0538700021972
2015-02-28  Residential Pool    ND,5    BDM IT0538700021972
2015-02-28  Residential Pool    ND,6    BDM IT0538700021972
```

The autofilter should look for ND,5 in the AR7 column (wich is the 3rd column)

Here is the code that works great until the AR codes are not consequential anymore. As you can see in the recordset there's no AR3, AR4, AR5 and AR6 columns. So the FilterField I dim in the code is 1 for the AR1 code, 2 for the AR2 code but not 3 for the AR7 code (it's 7). So the code returns an error 'cause there is no column 7 in the Autofilter Range. But the real problem is that even if there was a column 7 in that Range, the result would have been zero or wrong because the Autofilter would have searched in the column 7 instead of the column 3.

```
Sub LookFor_ND5()

'--------- Dim FilterField (the number of the column).
'          ActiveCell.Value comes from another workbook and lets say 
'          in this case is AR7, so FilterField will be 7 (instead of 3)

    Dim FilterField As String
    FilterField = Replace(ActiveCell.Value, "AR", "")

'--------- Dim Criteria1 (the ND_Code I have to search) -----------

    Dim ND_Code As String
    ND_Code = "ND,5"

'--------- Some code to get the right working path and file -----------

    Dim currentFldr As String
    DirNames = Split(ActiveWorkbook.Path, "\")
    currentFldr = DirNames(UBound(DirNames))

    PathString = Replace(currentFldr, "-", "")

    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Mutuiresidenziali_" & PathString & "_RES.xlsx"

    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(fileName)

'--------- AutoFilter -----------
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$6000").AutoFilter Field:=FilterField, Criteria1:=ND_Code

End Sub
```

How can I fix the code to get it work? To make the Autofilter look for the code in the right column?

Consider that I can't add fake columns to the file to fit the range.

Hope I explained myself well... Thanks in advance

---

### Working code

```
Sub LookFor_ND5()

'--------- Dim FilterField (the number of the column).

    Dim FilterField As String
    FilterField = ActiveCell.Value 'AR7

'--------- Dim Criteria1 (the ND_Code I have to search) -----------

    Dim ND_Code As String
    ND_Code = "ND,5"

'--------- Some code to get the right working path and file -----------

    Dim currentFldr As String
    DirNames = Split(ActiveWorkbook.Path, "\")
    currentFldr = DirNames(UBound(DirNames))

    PathString = Replace(currentFldr, "-", "")

    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Mutuiresidenziali_" & PathString & "_RES.xlsx"

    Set WB = Workbooks.Open(fileName)

'--------- AutoFilter -----------
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$6000").AutoFilter Field:=Application.Match(FilterField,
 Rows(1), 0), Criteria1:=ND_Code

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried to make *FilterField* **Long** or **Integer** ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MATCH to get the column position:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$6000").AutoFilter Field:=Application.Match("AR7", Activesheet.Rows(1), 0), Criteria1:=ND_Code
```

Comment: Jesus, so simple? It worked great. Where can I show the working code for everyone with the same issue? Thanks!!

Comment: @aurezio Show everyone the working code, and thank Rory by giving him an up vote and clicking the check mark. No need to mark the title `(solved)` though that's common practice at other sites.

Comment: @FreeMan Ok for the working code, ok for the SOLVED thing (I'll remove it) but I can't give an upvote to Rory 'cause I don't have enough reputations point... New user here, gotta learn how to use the forum :)

Comment: You can click the `answered` check mark. That will actually give you a couple of points! Also, be sure to take the tour, it will help.